# How to POST 2 String and 1 object From Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want post data like,

```
{
"name": "sample string 1",
"description": "sample string 2",
"address": {
  "street": "sample string 1",
  "landmark": "sample string 2",
  "buildingName": "sample string 3",
  "areaName": "sample string 4",
  "zipCode": "sample string 5",
  "latitude": 1.0,
  "longitude": 1.0,
  "mapLink": "sample string 6",
  "addressString": "sample string 7",
  "cityId": 8
}}
```

using Retrofit2. How can I pass all this?

Comment: Use [Body](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html) 
 annotation in your method argument to post this object.

Comment: Using Body i can only pass object, but what about strings

Comment: Nope, you can if you encapsulate those `two` strings with `address` object in a class.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

/**
 * Created by Rohan on 29-12-2017.
 */

public class Pojo {

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private Address address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pojo{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", address=" + address +
            '}';
}
```

}

//Make another Class for Address Entity as its a foreign key..
public class Address {

```
@SerializedName("street")
@Expose
private String street;
@SerializedName("landmark")
@Expose
private String landmark;
@SerializedName("buildingName")
@Expose
private String buildingName;
@SerializedName("areaName")
@Expose
private String areaName;
@SerializedName("zipCode")
@Expose
private String zipCode;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private Double latitude;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private Double longitude;
@SerializedName("mapLink")
@Expose
private String mapLink;
@SerializedName("addressString")
@Expose
private String addressString;
@SerializedName("cityId")
@Expose
private Integer cityId;

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getLandmark() {
    return landmark;
}

public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
    this.landmark = landmark;
}

public String getBuildingName() {
    return buildingName;
}

public void setBuildingName(String buildingName) {
    this.buildingName = buildingName;
}

public String getAreaName() {
    return areaName;
}

public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getMapLink() {
    return mapLink;
}

public void setMapLink(String mapLink) {
    this.mapLink = mapLink;
}

public String getAddressString() {
    return addressString;
}

public void setAddressString(String addressString) {
    this.addressString = addressString;
}

public Integer getCityId() {
    return cityId;
}

public void setCityId(Integer cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address{" +
            "street='" + street + '\'' +
            ", landmark='" + landmark + '\'' +
            ", buildingName='" + buildingName + '\'' +
            ", areaName='" + areaName + '\'' +
            ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
            ", latitude=" + latitude +
            ", longitude=" + longitude +
            ", mapLink='" + mapLink + '\'' +
            ", addressString='" + addressString + '\'' +
            ", cityId=" + cityId +
            '}';
}
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTXx1.png)

```
  @Post("yourURLForPostMethod")
  Call<ResponseClass> response(@Body Pojo pojo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  Create model and send as  `@Body`

RequestPojo.java

```
    public class RequestPojo {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
    return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
    }

    }


    public class Address {

    @SerializedName("street")
    @Expose
    private String street;
    @SerializedName("landmark")
    @Expose
    private String landmark;
    @SerializedName("buildingName")
    @Expose
    private String buildingName;
    @SerializedName("areaName")
    @Expose
    private String areaName;
    @SerializedName("zipCode")
    @Expose
    private String zipCode;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private Double latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private Double longitude;
    @SerializedName("mapLink")
    @Expose
    private String mapLink;
    @SerializedName("addressString")
    @Expose
    private String addressString;
    @SerializedName("cityId")
    @Expose
    private Integer cityId;

    public String getStreet() {
    return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
    }

    public String getLandmark() {
    return landmark;
    }

    public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
    this.landmark = landmark;
    }

    public String getBuildingName() {
    return buildingName;
    }

    public void setBuildingName(String buildingName) {
    this.buildingName = buildingName;
    }

    public String getAreaName() {
    return areaName;
    }

    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getMapLink() {
    return mapLink;
    }

    public void setMapLink(String mapLink) {
    this.mapLink = mapLink;
    }

    public String getAddressString() {
    return addressString;
    }

    public void setAddressString(String addressString) {
    this.addressString = addressString;
    }

    public Integer getCityId() {
    return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(Integer cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    }
```

APIInterface.java

```
    public interface APIInterface {

        @POST("send")
        Call<ResponseModel> register(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> header, @Body RequestPojo requestPojo);

    }
```

API :

```
    RequestPojo requestPojo=new RequestPojo();
    requestPojo.setDescription("Desc");
    requestPojo.setName("Name");

    RequestPojo.Address address=new RequestPojo().new Address();
    address.setAddressString("sjdo");

    requestPojo.setAddress(address);
    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
    header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    APIInterface appInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    System.out.println("Final" + new Gson().toJson(requestPojo));

    Call<ResponseModel> call = appInterface.register(header, requestPojo);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<UpgradeAsCorporateResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass class object through @Body parameter. Here I have converted your json file to two model classes ApiInput and Address. You can pass object of AiInput model class. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
public class ApiInput {

private String name;
private String description;
private Address address;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public Address getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
this.address = address;
}

}


public class Address {

private String street;
private String landmark;
private String buildingName;
private String areaName;
private String zipCode;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;
private String mapLink;
private String addressString;
private Integer cityId;

public String getStreet() {
return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
this.street = street;
}

public String getLandmark() {
return landmark;
}

public void setLandmark(String landmark) {
this.landmark = landmark;
}

public String getBuildingName() {
return buildingName;
}

public void setBuildingName(String buildingName) {
this.buildingName = buildingName;
}

public String getAreaName() {
return areaName;
}

public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
this.areaName = areaName;
}

public String getZipCode() {
return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getMapLink() {
return mapLink;
}

public void setMapLink(String mapLink) {
this.mapLink = mapLink;
}

public String getAddressString() {
return addressString;
}

public void setAddressString(String addressString) {
this.addressString = addressString;
}

public Integer getCityId() {
return cityId;
}

public void setCityId(Integer cityId) {
this.cityId = cityId;
}

}
```